# Dealing with middleware that requires access to the database in Go

Tags: go

I am having an issue with creating a middleware that will be chained to other routes and requires access to the database and am not sure how to approach this problem.

I store all of my app context, including the database in a struct called `AppContext`. I want to create a function handler that looks something like this:

```
    func SomeHandler(appC *AppContext, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
           // Access the database using appC.db
           // Logic that requires access to the database.

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
       return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
    }

}
```

In `main.go`, I have tried:

```
someHandler := middleware.SomeHandler(&appC)
```

However, I get the error `not enough arguments in call to middleware.SomeHandler`. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: As an aside contexts are a thing in Go, https://golang.org/pkg/context/, so that appContext name may get confusing.

Comment: Frankly: reading the docs and [taking the tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). You should at least be able to read method signatures before you take any further steps. Furthermore, I'd refrain from setting up an "uber"-context identical for all requests.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to not providing the second argument, `next http.Handler`.

In the case of how to go about the middleware, I recommend taking a look at the implementation of the `http.ServeMux` https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=57308:57433#L1890 it essentially does what you're trying to do (and then some) for routing though.  So using a http.Handler struct might be more easy here than using a Handler function, this way the Handler(s) you'd have as the `next http.Handler` argument in your function are just a field within the struct that the parent handler can call from within its `ServeHTTP()`.

So to wrap up my point, you might want to use a struct that implements the `http.Handler` interface.  That way it can have child handlers and the DB access.  That way you don't have to keep passing this `AppContext` either.

Answer (score -1):

I'd not do a premature setup of the context. It is specifically there to be request scoped.

I'd rather create a small and dedicated middleware for passing a database session out of the pool *into* the context and retrieve said session created for the request in the main handler.

```
func DBSession(sess *mgo.Session, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Create a new session for the scope of the request
            s := sess.Copy()
            // Make it close when exiting scope
            defer s.Close()

            // Add the new session (actually a pointer to it)
            // acessible via the name "_sess"
            ctx = context.WithValue(r.Context(), "_sess", s)

            // execute the next handler
            next(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
        })
}
```

Now you can use this middleware in you main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) http.Handler{

  return http.HandlerFunc(
    func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      s := r.Context().Value("_sess").(*mgo.Session)
      // Do something with your database here.
    }
  )

}

func main() {

    // Ignoring err for brevity
    sess, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")

    // Magic happens here: the sayHello Handler is wrapped in the
    // DBSession middleware, which makes the session available
    // as context param _sess and closes the session after sayHello
    // executed. No clutter in your controller for setting up and tearing down
    // the session, no way you can forget to close it.
    http.Handle("/", middleware.DBSession(sess, sayHello))
}
```